# Make a div disappear or add display:none; with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I use a specific JavaScript document that allows me to switch easily between different pages in only one HTML document (https://github.com/icodebuster/transition.js).

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="pt-wrapper">
<div class="pt-trigger-container">
    <button class="pt-trigger pt-btn1" id="btn_bot" data-animation="3" data-goto="-1"></button>
    <button class="pt-trigger pt-btn2" data-animation="2" data-goto="-2"></button>
</div>

<!--All Pages-->

<div class="head_wrapper">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="menu"></div>
</div>

<div class="pt-page pt-page-1">
  *Page1 Code*    
</div>
<div class="pt-page pt-page-2">
  *Page2 Code*              
</div>
<div class="pt-page pt-page-3">
  *Page3 Code*    
</div>  ETC...
```

I want to modify my jQuery code to make appear and disappear some buttons when I'm in a specific page. For example here, when I click on my first pt-trigger button, it switches for the next page (data-goto="-1" is relative to next page and -2 for previous page switch). The jQuery code adds a 'pt-page-current' class to the current page showed in browser.

Here is the jQuery relative to this system:

```
// This will get the pt-trigger elements parent wrapper div
    var $pageWrapper = $pageTrigger.closest('.pt-wrapper');
    var currentPageIndex = $pageWrapper.data('current'), tempPageIndex,
        $pages = $pageWrapper.children('div.pt-page'),
        pagesCount = $pages.length,
        endCurrentPage = false,
        endNextPage = false;

    gotoPage = parseInt($pageTrigger.data('goto'));

    // check if 'data-goto' value is greater than total pages inside 'pt-wrapper'
    if (!(pagesCount < gotoPage)) {

        tempPageIndex = currentPageIndex;

        if($pageWrapper.data('isAnimating')) {
            return false;
        }

        // Setting the isAnimating property to true.
        $pageWrapper.data('isAnimating', true);

        // Current page to be removed.
        var $currentPage = $pages.eq(currentPageIndex);

        // Checking gotoPage value and decide what to do
        // -1 Go to next page
        // -2 Go to previous page
        // 0+ Go to custom page number.
        // NEXT PAGE
        if (gotoPage == -1) {

            // Incrementing page counter to diplay next page
            if(currentPageIndex < pagesCount - 1) {
                ++currentPageIndex;
            }
            else {
                currentPageIndex = 0;
            }
        }
        // PREVOUS PAGE
        else if (gotoPage == -2) {
            if (currentPageIndex == 0){
                currentPageIndex = pagesCount - 1;

            }
            else if(currentPageIndex <= pagesCount - 1 ) {
                --currentPageIndex;
            }
            else {
                currentPageIndex = 0;
            }

        }
        // GOTO PAGE
        else {
            currentPageIndex = gotoPage - 1 ;
        }

        // Check if the current page is same as the next page then do not do the animation
        // else reset the 'isAnimatiing' flag
        if (tempPageIndex != currentPageIndex) {
            $pageWrapper.data('current', currentPageIndex);

            // Next page to be animated.
            var $nextPage = $pages.eq(currentPageIndex).addClass('pt-page-current');

            $currentPage.addClass(outClass).on(animEndEventName, function() {
                $currentPage.off(animEndEventName);
                endCurrentPage = true;
                if(endNextPage) {
                    onEndAnimation($pageWrapper, $nextPage, $currentPage);
                }
            });

            $nextPage.addClass(inClass).on(animEndEventName, function() {
                $nextPage.off(animEndEventName);
                endNextPage = true;
                if(endCurrentPage) {
                    onEndAnimation($pageWrapper, $nextPage, $currentPage);
                }
            });

        }
        else {
            $pageWrapper.data('isAnimating', false);
        }

    }
    else {
        alert("Transition.js : Invalid 'data-goto' attribute configuration.");
    }

    // Check if the animation is supported by browser and reset the pages.
    if(!support) {
        onEndAnimation($currentPage, $nextPage);
    }

}

function onEndAnimation($pageWrapper, $nextPage, $currentPage) {
    resetPage($nextPage, $currentPage);
    $pageWrapper.data('isAnimating', false);
}

function resetPage($nextPage, $currentPage) {
    $currentPage.attr('class', $currentPage.data('originalClassList'));
    $nextPage.attr('class', $nextPage.data('originalClassList') + ' pt-page-current');
}

return {
    init : init,
};

})();

$(document).ready(function() {
    // initializing page transition.
    PageTransitions.init();
});
```

I tried to add this function to the code but it doesn't worked :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if(currentPageIndex >= 3){
    $("#btn_bot").addClass(".btn_hide");
}
```

I tried here to make the bottom button relative to next page disappear by adding the class `btn_hide` that contains only a `display: none;` CSS property but only when I'm at the page 3 or more.

Comment: So this If statement will be invoked once when the document is first made ready. You need to invoke that function any time a transition occurs rather than just once on page load in order to continually check the status of your page

Comment: +1 Off topic, but have you considered using something like Knockout/Angular/Backbone for this project?  It seems like this would be a pretty good use case.  jQuery gets sort of hairy in these types of scenarios.

Comment: Hey, maybe not the problem, but are you sure about ".btn_hide"? The . is used in Css to say that you specify a class, but is not required on the addClass in javascript. Try addClass("btn_hide")

Comment: @mcclaskiem, it's true I didn't thinked to it !
:alex, I'm a designer so I don't have enough time to learn others simplified js langages... And I use an external code from codrops maded in jQuery so...
:RaNdoM_PoWneD, you'r right ! It's a mistake due to my inexperimentation in js

Answer (score 0):

you could move your if into a function and add an onclick to check the current page in addition to calling the function on document.ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkPage()
};
$(document).on('click',function(){
    checkPage()
});

function checkPage(){
    if(currentPageIndex >= 3){
    $("#btn_bot").addClass("btn_hide");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use show() and hide() functions and add onclick() event to your buttons

```
<div class="pt-trigger-container">
    <button onclick="gotoPage(this)" class="pt-trigger pt-btn1" id="btn_bot" data-animation="3" data-goto="-1"></button>
    <button onclick="gotoPage(this)" class="pt-trigger pt-btn2" data-animation="2" data-goto="-2"></button>
</div>
```

And inside this function write something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function gotoPage(checkedButton){
            var pageIndex = $(checkedButton).data('goto');
            // TODO: paste your currentPageIndex calculation here
            if (currentPageIndex >= 3) {
                $("#btn_bot").show();
            }
            else { 
                $("#btn_bot").hide();
            }
        }

        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == '38') {
                // up arrow
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
                // down arrow
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
                // left arrow
                $('.pt-btn1').click();
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
                // right arrow
                $('.pt-btn2').click();
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, with this solution can I add scroll and arrows navigation or this is only for button click transition ?

Comment: Arrow navigation ? I'm not sure that I understand you correctly. Am I right you want to add navigation by using keyboard buttons left arrow and right arrow ? Or you just want to add picture with arrow to the buttons with classes .pt-btn1 and .pt-btn2 ?

Comment: I mean using the keyboard buttons yes (the four directions) !

Comment: of course you can do it! See my updates in the script

Comment: You rocks Tequila, I'll try to make this work with my noob skills hehe